# Software to perform RAID on different drive technology (IDE, SATA, SCSI, SSD)

Tags: sata, pata, scsi

May I know if there is any software (in Windows) that can perform RAID on different type of drive technology in a single computer?

From my understanding, Hardware RAID card is needed to perform RAID on the same type of drive technology in a single computer. (Do correct me if I have misunderstand). Therefore, if a SCSI Disk is used in RAID, the second and so forth Disk is usually SCSI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it is not technically RAID, creating a [JBOD (Just A Bunch Of Disks)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-RAID_drive_architectures) span can yield results similar to RAID.  Also, all of Intel's RAID controllers that I have dealt with in recent years (ICH8R and above) have never complained about discs being different when I create a RAID array... it just figures it out.

Comment: from your answer, can I assume that only hardware RAID can perform RAID and also in the practical real world, there is no actual software that can perform RAID on different type of drive technology under Windows OS?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge there is no software that will provide RAID functionality below Windows, but you can use Windows built in RAID functionality. I have never used it but from what I read it gets the job done if you for some reason cannot use a dedicated RAID controller. Read [here](http://kmwoley.com/blog/?p=429) and [here](http://www.techimo.com/articles/index.pl?photo=149).

Answer (score 0):

> is any windows software  that can perform RAID on different type of drive
>   technology in a single computer?

Yes, there is. It is called Microsoft windows (as in the OS itself).

E.g. see this screenshot in Windows 10 preview (though it works the same in windows 7. But I have no mixed drives there to test it with).

[image: Screenshot of a win 10 preview VM with a SCSI and a SATA drive in a mirror]

> From my understanding, a hardware RAID card is needed to perform RAID on
>   the same type of drive technology in a single computer. 
>   (Do correct me if I have misunderstand).

I am not sure it if it needed. There is no technical reason why a RAID card could not create an array on a mix of e.g. SAS and SATA disks.

> Therefore, if a SCSI drive is used in RAID, the second and so forth drive is
>   usually SCSI.

Usually yes.

- Mixing technologies gives you the worst of both. (E.g. you are mixing usually more expansive SCSI and SAS drives with the reliability of cheap PATA/SATA disks).
- Mising technologies also means that the RAID cards get more complex (it must understand/posses both interfaces)